# Refined Duskin Nerve

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

The Duskin nerve sends a 2-category C to the simplicial set whose $n$-th term
is the set of normal lax 2-functors $[n] \to C.$
The Duskin nerve gives a full embedding from the category of 2-categories and normal lax
2-functors into the category of simplicial sets.

Let $\mathcal{O}_n$ be the 2-truncation of the $n$-th oriental.
Normal lax 2-functors $[n] \to C$ correspond to 2-functors $\mathcal{O}_n \to C$
and the Duskin nerve $[n] \mapsto Fun(\mathcal{O}_n,C)$ lifts to an embedding of the category of 2-categories and 2-functors $Cat_2$ into the category of scaled simplicial sets (= 2-trivial stratified simplicial sets) when an object of $ Fun(\mathcal{O}_1,C)$ is marked if it is the identity and an object of $Fun(\mathcal{O}_2,C)$ is marked when it sends the top non-degenerate 2-cell of $\mathcal{O}_2$ to a 2-isomorphism.

Is it also true that the assignment $\mathcal{O}_n \mapsto Fun(\mathcal{O}_n,C) $ gives an embedding of $Cat_2$ into presheaves on the full subcategory of $Cat_2$ spanned by $\mathcal{O}_n, n \geq 0$?